# Why does webpack tapable use new Function('xx', 'some string code') to generate a function instead of writing a function directly?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I don't understand what the benefits of doing this are.

I tried it myself and found that the new function is actually much slower than the direct execution of the code.

```js
case "sync":
fn = new Function(
                    this.args(),
                    '"use strict";\n' +
                        this.header() +
                        this.content({
                            onError: err => `throw ${err};\n`,
                            onResult: result => `return ${result};\n`,
                            onDone: () => "",
                            rethrowIfPossible: true
                        })
                );
                break;
```

Why not do it like this

```js
function async() {
  "use strict";
  some code......;
  onError: err => `throw ${err};\n`,
                            onResult: result => `return ${result};\n`,
                            onDone: () => "",
                            rethrowIfPossible: true
}
```

Comment: `function async` will throw a `SyntaxError`, `async` is a reserved keyword